# Implementing Snap-To-Edge Functionality

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I've written some code which implements snap-to-edge functionality for some windows.

There is some code duplication as you can see. I think this code can be simpler or possibly improved.

```
// If 'rtParent' and 'rtChild' are closed each other as 'ENABLE_STICK_VALUE', return true;  
auto IsNearEachOther = []( const QRect& rtParent, const QRect& rtChild ) -> std::tuple< bool, QPoint>
{
    bool isNear = false;
    QPoint ptMoveTarget;

    // If 'rtChild's left position is closing to 'rtParent's right position.
    if ( rtChild.left() > rtParent.right() )
    {
        if ( ( ( rtChild.left() - rtParent.right() ) <= ENABLE_STICK_VALUE )
            && ( rtChild.top() >= ( rtParent.top() - ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) )
            && ( rtChild.top() <= ( rtParent.bottom() + ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) ) )
        {
            isNear = true;
            ptMoveTarget = QPoint( rtParent.right(), rtParent.top() );
        }
    }

    // If 'rtChild's right position is closing to 'rtParent's left position.
    if ( rtChild.right() < rtParent.left() )
    {
        if ( ( ( rtParent.left() - rtChild.right() ) <= ENABLE_STICK_VALUE )
            && ( rtChild.top() >= ( rtParent.top() - ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) )
            && ( rtChild.top() <= ( rtParent.bottom() + ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) ) )
        {
            isNear = true;
            ptMoveTarget = QPoint( rtParent.left() - rtChild.width() , rtParent.top() );
        }
    }

    return std::make_tuple( isNear, ptMoveTarget );
};

QRect rtParent = m_pParentChatRoom->geometry();
QRect rtCurrent = geometry();

bool result = false;
QPoint ptMoveTarget;
std::tie( result, ptMoveTarget ) = IsNearEachOther( rtParent, rtCurrent );
if ( result )
{
    move( ptMoveTarget );
}
```

Comment: That function is large for a lambda. Regardless of being some inner function inside some other function, it is probably time to make it a proper member of some class or an ordinary namespace-level function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely [extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) for the following code:

```
if ( rtChild.right() < rtParent.left() )
{
    if ( ( ( rtParent.left() - rtChild.right() ) <= ENABLE_STICK_VALUE )
        && ( rtChild.top() >= ( rtParent.top() - ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) )
        && ( rtChild.top() <= ( rtParent.bottom() + ENABLE_STICK_VALUE ) ) )
    {
        isNear = true;
        ptMoveTarget = QPoint( rtParent.left() - rtChild.width() , rtParent.top() );
    }
}
```

Where you can pass through a left/right variable however you want and then change:

`rtParent.left() - rtChild.width()` to rely on the given parameter, falling back onto `rtParent.right()`

The same can be said for any other small changes in the code, such as

`rtChild.right() < rtParent.left()`
versus
`rtChild.left() > rtParent.right()`

I'm not going to give you the exact solution, but that `if` condition holds most of the repeated code and can be brought out into something like `snapTo(right/left)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've accept your answer, however I've altered the code using other api, such as `QRect::adjusted(), QRect::contains()`. If you have some spare time, I want to you check my [altered code](https://gist.github.com/surinkim/7d01fe3260ae221dc887), and listen to your thought. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yeah that looks nice. Very readable. I don't have much time to got through it, but it definitely is an improvement, granted it works how you wanted to still :)